# pata hard disk I/O error in 2 sectors

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, io, pata

after deleting all partitions and creating one fat32 partition, I got this error in the terminal and then I ran GSmartControl and got a report.
and also the chkdsk gave me an error `An error occurred while reading file allocation table (FAT 1)` .

now I want to know if the hard disk is repairable or not?

[blkid report image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0LLn.jpg)

and the GSmartControl report:

```
smartctl 6.5 2016-05-07 r4318 [x86_64-linux-4.7.6-200.fc24.x86_64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Western Digital Caviar
Device Model:     WDC WD800BB-22JHC0
Serial Number:    WD-WMAM9ACC8047
Firmware Version: 05.01C05
User Capacity:    80,025,280,000 bytes [80.0 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA/ATAPI-6 (minor revision not indicated)
Local Time is:    Thu Dec 29 12:36:04 2016 EET
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: FAILED!
Drive failure expected in less than 24 hours. SAVE ALL DATA.
See vendor-specific Attribute list for failed Attributes.

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x82) Offline data collection activity
                    was completed without error.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        ( 2460) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    No General Purpose Logging support.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (  35) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   5) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x003f) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000f   198   198   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       11183
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0003   173   158   021    Pre-fail  Always       -       2333
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   097   097   000    Old_age   Always       -       3233
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   117   117   140    Pre-fail  Always   FAILING_NOW 661
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000f   172   098   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       3538
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   097   097   000    Old_age   Always       -       2381
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x0012   100   100   051    Old_age   Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   097   097   000    Old_age   Always       -       3096
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   110   084   000    Old_age   Always       -       33
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   001   001   000    Old_age   Always       -       1338
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0012   200   180   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0010   181   181   000    Old_age   Offline      -       256
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x003e   200   199   000    Old_age   Always       -       12
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x0009   076   076   051    Pre-fail  Offline      -       3972

SMART Error Log Version: 1
ATA Error Count: 14426 (device log contains only the most recent five errors)
    CR = Command Register [HEX]
    FR = Features Register [HEX]
    SC = Sector Count Register [HEX]
    SN = Sector Number Register [HEX]
    CL = Cylinder Low Register [HEX]
    CH = Cylinder High Register [HEX]
    DH = Device/Head Register [HEX]
    DC = Device Command Register [HEX]
    ER = Error register [HEX]
    ST = Status register [HEX]
Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as
DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes,
SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.

Error 14426 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 2381 hours (99 days + 5 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 01 10 03 00 e0  Error: UNC 1 sectors at LBA = 0x00000310 = 784

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  c8 00 01 10 03 00 00 58      00:24:23.460  READ DMA
  c8 00 01 10 03 00 00 58      00:24:21.480  READ DMA
  c8 00 01 10 03 00 00 58      00:24:19.365  READ DMA
  c8 00 01 10 03 00 00 58      00:24:17.095  READ DMA
  c8 00 01 10 03 00 00 58      00:24:14.980  READ DMA

Error 14425 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 2381 hours (99 days + 5 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 01 10 03 00 e0  Error: UNC 1 sectors at LBA = 0x00000310 = 784

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  c8 00 01 10 03 00 00 58      00:24:21.480  READ DMA
  c8 00 01 10 03 00 00 58      00:24:19.365  READ DMA
  c8 00 01 10 03 00 00 58      00:24:17.095  READ DMA
  c8 00 01 10 03 00 00 58      00:24:14.980  READ DMA
  c8 00 01 10 03 00 00 58      00:24:13.015  READ DMA

Error 14424 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 2381 hours (99 days + 5 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 01 10 03 00 e0  Error: UNC 1 sectors at LBA = 0x00000310 = 784

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  c8 00 01 10 03 00 00 58      00:24:19.365  READ DMA
  c8 00 01 10 03 00 00 58      00:24:17.095  READ DMA
  c8 00 01 10 03 00 00 58      00:24:14.980  READ DMA
  c8 00 01 10 03 00 00 58      00:24:13.015  READ DMA
  c8 00 07 09 03 00 00 58      00:24:13.015  READ DMA

Error 14423 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 2381 hours (99 days + 5 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 01 10 03 00 e0  Error: UNC 1 sectors at LBA = 0x00000310 = 784

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  c8 00 01 10 03 00 00 58      00:24:17.095  READ DMA
  c8 00 01 10 03 00 00 58      00:24:14.980  READ DMA
  c8 00 01 10 03 00 00 58      00:24:13.015  READ DMA
  c8 00 07 09 03 00 00 58      00:24:13.015  READ DMA
  c8 00 01 08 03 00 00 58      00:24:13.015  READ DMA

Error 14422 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 2381 hours (99 days + 5 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 01 10 03 00 e0  Error: UNC 1 sectors at LBA = 0x00000310 = 784

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  c8 00 01 10 03 00 00 58      00:24:14.980  READ DMA
  c8 00 01 10 03 00 00 58      00:24:13.015  READ DMA
  c8 00 07 09 03 00 00 58      00:24:13.015  READ DMA
  c8 00 01 08 03 00 00 58      00:24:13.015  READ DMA
  ec 00 01 00 00 00 00 58      00:24:13.015  IDENTIFY DEVICE

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of those errors say the same thing. You have a dead sector at 784 and there is nothing the drive can do about it.

The drive *might* have been able to do something about that sector had there not been this line in your SMART status:

```
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   117   117   140    Pre-fail  Always   FAILING_NOW 661
```

It might have been able to reallocate that sector and carry on, but that drive went past that point of being able to do that quite some time ago.

All the other SMART status messages indicate a drive that is, if not already dead, is something you do not want to store any data you care about on.

Given that the drive is [$21 from newegg](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16822144102) I wouldn't consider this drive worth the effort.

Comment: is it possible to force write this sector? 
I had read this blog `http://www.sj-vs.net/forcing-a-hard-disk-to-reallocate-bad-sectors/` , and I'm willing to do this.

Comment: @ĂľBřĭńŝẴĥmễď The sector has probably been attempted to be rewritten when you formatted it, it is *physically* defective otherwise it wouldn't have been attempted to be remapped along with the other defective sectors. The disk is defective and no longer usable.